# How can I create a subrouter with React Router v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

Here is my current React Router implementation:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: (
        <Page activeNav="home" >
          <Home />
        </Page>
      )
    },
    {
      path: "/about",
      element: (
        <Page activeNav="about" >
          <About />
        </Page>
      )
    },
    {
      path: "/blog",
      element: (
        <Page activeNav="blog">
          <Blog />
        </Page>
      )
    },
    {
      path: "/blog/:postName",
      element: (
        <Page activeNav="blog" >
          <Post />
        </Page>
      ),
      loader: ({ params }) => params.postName
    },
    {
      path: "/chess",
      element: <ChessRouter />
    }
  ])
```

The last route, `/chess` is of importance. I am looking to define routes such as `/chess/play`, `/chess/login`, `/chess/register`, etc. My initial idea was to just put another `Router` as the element for the `/chess` path and then all those paths would be routed from there. However, that throws an error saying:

```
You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>. You should never have more than one in your app.
```

I also tried using the children property on the `/chess` route but this does not render anything when I go to `/chess/play` etc.

What is the correct way of implementing subpaths (not sure of the correct word for it)?

Comment: can you use this : `<Route path="chess" element={<User />}>
          <Route path="play" element={<Play />} />
          <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="register" element={<Register />} />
        </Route>`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is correct that you cannot render a router component within another router component as this is an invariant violation. You need only one router and routing context per React app.

To render sub-routes on `"/chess"` then there are two options:

1. Render nested routes in the routes configuration declaration. This ***requires*** the `ChessRouter` component to render an `Outlet` component for nested routes to render their `element` content into. Nested routes will be able to use the new RRDv6.4 Data APIs.

   ```
   const router = createBrowserRouter([
     ...,
     {
       path: "/chess",
       element: <ChessRouter />,
       children: [
         ...,
         {
           path: "play",
           element: <ChessPlay />
         },
         ... other chess sub-rotues
       ],
     }
   ]);
   ```

   ```
   const ChessRouter = () => {
     ...

     return (
       ...
       <Outlet />
       ...
     );
   };
   ```
2. Render a root route with trailing wildcard (*`"*"`*) character that allows descendent routes to also be matched. This allows the `ChessRouter` component to render descendent routes, i.e. a `Routes` component with a set of `Route` components. Descendent routes ***will not*** be able to use the RRDv6.4 Data APIs.

   ```
   const router = createBrowserRouter([
     ...,
     {
       path: "/chess/*",
       element: <ChessRouter />,
     }
   ]);
   ```

   ```
   const ChessRouter = () => {
     ...

     return (
       ...
       <Routes>
         ...
         <Route path="/play" element={<ChessPlay />} />
         ... other chess sub-rotues
       </Routes>
       ...
     );
   };
   ```

Answer (score 5):

If your ChessRouter does not contain any additional functionality besides route declarations, you could drop it altogether and use an index route.

Working off of what Drew had:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  ...,
  {
    path: "/chess",
    children: [{
        index: true,
        element: <ChessPlay />    // The default component to load at '/chess'
      },
      {
        path: "play",
        element: <ChessPlay />
      },
      ... other chess sub-rotues
    ],
  }
]);
```

This will let all of your child routes under /chess work as well as prevent an empty page from showing if a user hits the base /chess route.